# Rx fromPromise not recognizing then as a function?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I am trying to use `rx-lite` in a `react` component.  I am passing `Rx.Observable.fromPromise` an `axios` http request.  `axios` returns a `promise` so it should find the `.then`. Here is my component.

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            results: []
        }
        this.handleOnBlur = this.handleOnBlur.bind(this);
        this.handleOnBlurDebounced = this.handleOnBlur.debounce(250, false);
        this.getResults = this.getResults.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.subscription = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(this.getResults)          
            .map(res => this.setState({
                results: res.data.return
            }));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.subscription.dispose();
    }

    getResults() {
        return axios.get('/results');
    }

    handleOnBlur() {
        this.subscription.forEach();
    }

    render() {
      ...
    }
}
```

In my `componentDidMount`, I call `this.getResults`.  I get this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._p.then is not a function
```

If I use `this.getResults()`, it does make the call, but not lazily.  What do I need to change to make this work?

Comment: `this.getResults` is a function and does not have a `.then` method?

Comment: `this.getResults` is returning an `axios.get` function which does have a `.then` method.

Comment: Not when you're not calling it. [`fromPromise`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/frompromise.md) takes promises, not functions that return promises.

Comment: You are right.  And now I think about it, it completely makes sense.  Please make a answer that I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my componentDidMount, I call `this.getResults`

No, you didn't call it if you're not using `this.getResults()`. [`fromPromise`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/frompromise.md) takes a promise, not the promise-returning function that you passed.